# Merge 2 linked list without difficulties

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to write a function that will merge 2 linked lists and return the merged list. I did it, but I had to use `lastPtr`. The problem was that the last while loop iteration creates one more node than necessary. So the question is how can i remove the useless `lastPtr`?

There is the code:

```
NodePtr merge(NodePtr s1, NodePtr s2)
{
    NodePtr s3, currPtr, lastPtr;
    s3 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    currPtr = s3;

    while(s1 != NULL){
        currPtr->ch = s1->ch;
        currPtr->nextPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        currPtr = currPtr->nextPtr;
        s1 = s1->nextPtr;
    }

    while(s2 != NULL){
        lastPtr = currPtr;
        currPtr->ch = s2->ch;
        currPtr->nextPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        currPtr = currPtr->nextPtr;
        s2 = s2->nextPtr;
    }

    lastPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
    return s3;
}
```

Comment: First check that your lists are not empty, second change the conditions in the loop by `while(s1->nextptr!=NULL)`

Comment: The above code allocates one `Node` too many and throws away the last one (a memory leak).

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `lastPtr` by using a `Node **` (or `NodePtr *`) variable to point to the `->nextPtr` link.  It can also point to the head of list variable `s3`.  This allows the code to be implemented without a special case for creating the first element of the list:

```
NodePtr merge(NodePtr s1, NodePtr s2)
{
    NodePtr s3 = NULL;
    NodePtr *currPtrPtr = &s3;

    while(s1 != NULL){
        *currPtrPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        (*currPtrPtr)->ch = s1->ch;
        currPtrPtr = &(*currPtrPtr)->nextPtr;
        s1 = s1->nextPtr;
    }

    while(s2 != NULL){
        *currPtrPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        (*currPtrPtr)->ch = s2->ch;
        currPtrPtr = &(*currPtrPtr)->nextPtr;
        s2 = s2->nextPtr;
    }

    *currPtrPtr = NULL;
    return s3;
}
```